Statistical test to see whether one group is larger than the other
I have a data set that contains percentages of benefits provided in 2 groups from 2020 to 2023. Any statistical test I can use to test whether the percentages for group A are greater than the ones for group B? Sample size is 4 for each group so it's really small.
Group Year Number_of_plans Plans_with_benefits Percentage
A     2020 51              51                  100
A     2021 160             160                 100
A     2022 220             220                 100
A     2023 320             320                 100
B     2020 4472            1617                40
B     2021 4905            1876                42
B     2022 4905            2205                46
B     2023 5082            2496                49.1


How are the percentages calculated? If they are proportions of the form $x/n$, any test will need both $x$ and $n$. Please edit your post to add this information. Do not only give a comment!

I updated my post

In the table provided 100% of group A's plans have benefits. Is this the case in the full data, perhaps due to regulations that mean benefits are always approved for group A? (Also, is the table all the data you are working with?)

Any statistical test with 2*4 observations will have terrible power, and looking at the given numbers percentages are obviously strikingly different, so I don't think it makes sense to add artificial authority to the statement by running a formal test. The situation becomes different of course if every single plan is seen as an observation (as done in the answer of Igor F.), but here you might worry about the assumption of independence between observations, and whether the test just detects something that is implicit already in the definition/collection of observations.

It seems to me that you can reduce your data to a simple 2 $\times$ 2 contingency table and run a $\chi^2$ test on it.
If you just want to compare the groups, the time variable is irrelevant. You can combine the numbers in each group by adding them over the years. You'll notice that in the group A, there are some 750 plans and the same number of benefits. In the group B, you have some 19,000 plans, but only 8,000 with benefits. (All numbers are rounded.)
